# Setting Work Schedule with Outlook an half hour boundaries

Tags: ms-office

We use Outlook at work for scheduling. By default, the work schedule is 9AM to 5PM. You can easily change this to other hours under Preferences, but you are limited to full hour boundaries. I can't, for example, change my start time to 8:30AM, I can only choose 8AM or 9AM.

Is there is away to set a start time and end time on half hour boundaries?

Comment: what Mac's are you using and what MS office/Outlook

Comment: Outlook for Mac 2011, running on OS X 10.9.5. (Running on a MacBook Pro 15 Retina if that matters...)

Comment: It does matter, since you can do that on MS for windows but not on MS for Mac.

Comment: Well... this is Ask Different so isn't Mac assumed? Oh well, thanks for trying, it is annoying...

Comment: you would wonder how many questions we get that are not only not Mac related but not even PC-Windows related, from cooking to dating ect..:)

Comment: back to your question, the best you can do is use a out of office appointment (call it what you want), that ends at 8:30 AM, so no other appointments can be made at that time.

Comment: Please put that in an answer and I'll drop some rep points on you... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a limitation of the Outlook.

I use a work around.

I have set up a repeating event 7-8:30 for every work day, and marked it as "out of office" status, and Private and named it "do not disturb".

At least in the view now my work day starts at 8:30, and no one can call me in a god forsaken way to early meeting.